# Remove change made by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I made radio buttons that select a payment method, and when `Cash` is selected the `Tip` field is hidden and the amount is removed from the `Total`.

jQuery:

```
  $(':radio[id=Cash]').change(function() {
    $("#tip-area").addClass("hidden");
    $('#order-total').html(parseFloat($('#order-total').html() - $('#tip').val()).toFixed(2));
  });

  $(':radio[id!=Cash]').change(function(){
    $("#tip-area").removeClass("hidden");
    $('#order-total').html(parseFloat($('#order-total').html()) + parseFloat($('#tip').val()));
  });
```

So this works as expected, except when a person switches back and forth between the sections.

What is the best way to implement removing of the original change.

Example:
Customer selects `Cash` -> `Tip` field is removed and subtracted from `Total`.
Customer then selects a different payment method -> `Tip` field is un-hidden and the original math was reverted to its original state, displaying total and the generic tip amount/percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the total in a variable.

```
  var storedTotal = parseFloat($('#order-total').html());
  $(':radio[id=Cash]').change(function() {
    $("#tip-area").addClass("hidden");
    $('#order-total').html(parseFloat(storedTotal - $('#tip').val()).toFixed(2));
  });

  $(':radio[id!=Cash]').change(function(){
    $("#tip-area").removeClass("hidden");
    $('#order-total').html(storedTotal + parseFloat($('#tip').val()));
  });
```

Comment: Thank you - I've tried storing it before but it didn't work. The only change I've made was to remove the bottom addition of adding storedTotal again as it doubled the tip instead of reverting to original.

Comment: Yup, with storing the the value of Tip tip prior to change, then reverting to that state, it persists regardless of the amount of switched. Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve this by not relying on the value fetched from HTML and setting your own variables in your script.

Example:

```
var total = 100;

$(':radio[id=Cash]').change(function() {
    $("#tip-area").addClass("hidden");
    var total = $('#order-total').val();
    var tip = $('#tip').val();
    var newTotal = total - tip;
    $('#order-total').html(newTotal.toFixed(2));
});

$(':radio[id!=Cash]').change(function(){
    $("#tip-area").removeClass("hidden");
    $('#order-total').html(total.toFixed(2));
  });
```